# Find() vs. Where().FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I often see people using `Where.FirstOrDefault()` to do a search and grab the first element. Why not just use `Find()`? Is there an advantage to the other? I couldn't tell a difference.

```
namespace LinqFindVsWhere
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list.AddRange(new string[]
            {
                "item1",
                "item2",
                "item3",
                "item4"
            });

            string item2 = list.Find(x => x == "item2");
            Console.WriteLine(item2 == null ? "not found" : "found");
            string item3 = list.Where(x => x == "item3").FirstOrDefault();
            Console.WriteLine(item3 == null ? "not found" : "found");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `list.FirstOrDefault(x => x == "item3");` is more concise than using both `.Where` and `.FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @Kirk, I guess my next question would be why did they add the find at all. That is a good tip. The only thing I can think of is that the FirstOrDefault could return a different default value other than null. Otherwise it just seems like a pointless addition.

Comment: `Find` predates LINQ.  (it was available in .NET 2.0 and you couldn't use lambdas.  You were forced to use normal methods or anonymous methods)

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Where is the `Find` method on `IEnumerable<T>`? (Rhetorical question.)

The `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` methods are applicable against multiple kinds of sequences, including `List<T>`, `T[]`, `Collection<T>`, etc. Any sequence that implements `IEnumerable<T>` can use these methods. `Find` is available only for the `List<T>`. Methods that are generally more applicable, are then more *reusable* and have a greater impact.

> I guess my next question would be why did they add the find at all. That is a good tip. The only thing I can think of is that the FirstOrDefault could return a different default value other than null. Otherwise it just seems like a pointless addition

`Find` on `List<T>` predates the other methods. `List<T>` was added with generics in .NET 2.0, and `Find` was part of the API for that class. `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` were added as extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>` with Linq, which is a later .NET version. I cannot say with certainty that if Linq existed with the 2.0 release that `Find` would never have been added, but that is arguably the case for many other features that came in earlier .NET versions that were made obsolete or redundant by later versions.

Comment: Just to complement: There is no need to call Where and First or FirstOrDefault: either First or FirstOrDefault allows you to specify a search predicate, making the Where call unnecessary

Comment: But `Where(condition).FirstOrDefault()` optimizes at least as well and sometimes better than `FirstOrDefault(condition)` alone. We always use `Where()` to get the improved performance when available.

Comment: @Suncat2000 provide an example please

Comment: @Suncat2000 You're using Linq becasue of its expressive power and want to write declarative code. You should not be concerned with such micro improvements, which also can change in future implementations. Also, don't optimize too early

Comment: @suncat2000 I would like to verify that claim because if it faster then wouldn't firstordefault(predicate) just be implemented as where(predicate).firstordefault().

Comment: The optimization situation improved from EF4, that I was using, to EF6. Apparently somebody addressed the discrepancies and later versions no longer have to decide between the separate predicates. 5 seconds per query execution made a difference whether to further optimize or not, when multiplied by hundreds of transactions per day.

Answer (score 78):

I just found out today, doing some tests on a list of 80K objects and found that `Find()` can be up to 1000% faster than using a `Where` with `FirstOrDefault()`.
  I didn't know that until testing a timer before and after each call.
 Sometimes it was the same time, otherwise, it was faster.

see this https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-6602

Comment: Did you try it with Where AND FirstOrDefault? If you did perhaps try it with just only FirstOrDefault and see if Find() is still better.

Comment: @MVCKarl pls see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault). Find is really faster almost twice. But I can't figure out is this due to no Enumerator overhead only?

Comment: That sounds like you did not materialise the result with a `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to actually perform the query.

Comment: It is because `Find` makes use of the primary keys (hence indexes), whereas `Where` is a plain sql query

Comment: As of EF6, Find and FirstOrDefault both generate exactly the same SQL statements. You can see the SQL in a console app by doing  context.Database.Log = Console.Write; The sited example is using in-memory "Find" against a list of strings, not going against a DB with primary keys. Perhaps the statement translation of the Find clause - which omits the need to do lambda expression parsing is the reason for the performance improvement in this case. Against a database I doubt you'll notice a difference in RL situations... I also wonder if it was tested using Find first instead of second...

Comment: Well, this performance improvement is because find() check in cache for object before hitting DB whereas where() always to go DB to get object

Comment: This pertains to LINQ-to-Entities, rather than LINQ-to-objects as specified by the original poster.

Answer (score 50):

There is a very important difference if the source of the data is Entity Framework:  `Find` will  find entities in the 'added' state that are not yet persisted, but `Where` will not.  This is by design.

Comment: The `Find` method in the question is in no way related to EF's `Find` method.

Answer (score 31):

`Find` is only [implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) in `List<T>`, while `Where().FirstOrDefault()` works with all `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: And Find can be faster: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault

Answer (score 1):

For LINQ-2-Objects, there is no difference between something like `items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id)` and `items.Find(item => item.Id == id)`, since both enumerate over all items until a match is found. There can be performance differences when `items.Find(id)`, which can use a hashtable to find an object rather than using an iterator. So I guess to make performance measurements where this is an issue.

More importantly is the difference in behaviour when using **EntityFramework**, since `.FirstOrDefault()` executes a query and adds the result to the change tracker (by default; use `.AsTracking()`/`.AsNoTracking()` and the settings of the `DBContext` for override). The execution of `.FirstOrDefault()` might fail with an exception, when the object is already tracked by the change tracker.

`.Find()` will return the object that is already tracked by the change tracker in memory (ie. after an update or add). So this will not cause a problem when the object is already tracked.

Answer (score -1):

in addition to Anthony answer
`Where()` visit through all records and then return result(s) while `Find()` dont need to traverse through all records if predicate match with given predicate.

so say you have List of Test class having `id` and `name` properties.

```
 List<Test> tests = new List<Test>();
 tests.Add(new Test() { Id = 1, Name = "name1" });
 tests.Add(new Test() { Id = 2, Name = "name2" });
 tests.Add(new Test() { Id = 3, Name = "name3" });
 tests.Add(new Test() { Id = 4, Name = "name2" }); 
 var r = tests.Find(p => p.Name == "name2");
 Console.WriteLine(r.Id);
```

Will give output of `2`, and only **2** visits Find needed to give result , but if you use `Where().FirstOrDefault()` we will be visiting all records and then we get results.

So , when you know you only want first result from records in collection `Find()` will be more suitable then `Where().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: _but if you use Where().FirstOrDefault() we will be visiting all records and then we get results._ Nope. `FirstOrDefault` will 'bubble-up' the chain and stop enumerating everything. I use the term 'bubble-up' for lack of a better expression, because actually every selector/predicate will be passed on to the next, so the last method in the chain is actually doing work first.

Comment: Which means: this answer misses the mark completely.

Comment: I don't understand why to use Where(condition).FirstOrDefault(). This checks all the records and THEN filters the result. I guess it is NOT THE SAME thing as direct FirstOrDefault(condition) which should stop the search at the first valid record.

Answer (score -1):

`Find()` is the IEnumerable equivalent of a `FirstOrDefault()`. You should not chain both .Where() with `.FirstOrDefault()` because the `.Where()` goes through the whole array and then will iterate through that list to find the first item. You save an incredible amount of time by putting your search predicate in the `FirstOrDefault()` method.

Also, I encourage you to read the linked question to this thread to know more about the better performances on using the `.Find()` in specific scenarios [Performance of Find() vs. FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the answer above yours. Also, see Silvermind's comment on that answer.