# Lambda Expression for Finding properties

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to retreive `LineOfBusiness` property from `promotionCatalogResponseRootObject` where `PromotionID` is equal to `myId`

```
public class PromotionCatalogResponseRootObject
{
   public PromotionCatalogResponse PromotionCatalog { get; set; }
}

public class Promotion
{
  public string PromotionId { get; set; }
  public string LineOfBusiness { get; set; }
  public string PromotionName { get; set; }
}

public class PromotionCatalogResponse
{
  public List<Promotion> Promotion { get; set; }
}
```

I started off like this but I know I'm doing it wrong. Please guide

```
string myId = "7596";
string lineOfBusiness = dataPromotionCatalog.PromotionCatalog
                                            .Promotion.Find(p => p.LineOfBusiness);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are missing is the the `Find` method is expecting to receive a predicate with a `bool` return value but you are returning a `string`, the `LineOfBusiness` property.

First filter the items you want and then select the desired property. In addition, I'd go with the `Where` instead of the `Find`. ([Find() vs. Where().FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9335015/6400526))

```
var result = dataPromotionCatalog.PromotionCatalog.Promotion
                                 .Where(i => i.PromotionId == myId)
                                 .Select(i => i.LineOfBusiness);
```

or in query syntax

```
var result = (from item in dataPromotionCatalog.PromotionCatalog.Promotion
              where item.PromotionId == myId
              select item.LineOfBusiness);
```

If you are expecting/want to have one item then use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var result = dataPromotionCatalog.PromotionCatalog.Promotion
                 .FirstOrDefault(i => i.PromotionId == myId)?.LineOfBusiness;
```

Comment: What if I dont use `?.` and just use `.` ?

Comment: @HumaAli Then in the case that no item was found you will get a `NullReferenceException`. Check link I gave about `Null propagation`