# Is is better to use Find() or Single() to select an item from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am making an ASP.NET MVC application, and for actions like `Edit` or `Details` that require a single item, is it better to use `myDbContext.MyDbSet.Single(i => i.Id == id)` or `myDbContext.MyDbSet.Find(id)`? The latter is shorter, and in my opinion, cleaner without requiring the Linq method, but sources I have been reading on ASP.NET MVC seem to prefer the former.

I can't find a way to view the implementation, but if I had to guess, I'd say that `Single()` probably uses `Find()` somewhere along the way, which would indicate more method calls and somewhat inferior efficiency/performance. Is my thinking on this correct?

Comment: `.Find()` only works for `List<T>` right?

Comment: @Epic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Single throws an exception when there is not exactly record. It does not allow null values as Find does. There is more to it than just the performance.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, I was thinking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335015/find-vs-where-firstordefault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that `Find()` searches the first level cache of the `DbContext` first. If there is no hit, it will query the database. `Single()` will always query the database. In addition to that, `Find()` returns null when no entity was found. `Single()` will throw an exception. So the equivalent of `Find()` would be `SingleOrDefault()`.