# Get first value from table with where either have the value match or null with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table from which I want a value like this.
I need price info w.r.t. states and vendor, for example, I want to calculate the price for a state, my table has data like either vendor has a price or default price.

[image]

So if I look for VendorA in NY I should get 2000. And if I look for VendorA in LA it will give me 1500.
I can get this by

```
public long GetPrice(string State, string Vendor){
    var value = this.context.table.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.vendor == Vendor && a.state == State);

    if(value == null){
    value = this.context.table.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.vendor == null && a.state == State)?.Price;
    }
}

GetPrice("NY","VendorA"); //This should give me 2000.
GetPrice("LA","VendorA"); // This should give me 1500
```

Please suggest is there is some more optimized way, means Can I get in a single DB call.

Comment: What if you look for VendorB in CA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in one query by using:

```
private static long? GetPrice(string state, string vendor)
{
    return table
        .Where(x => x.State == state)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Vendor)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.State == state)
        ?.Price;
}
```

Filter out all prices in the matching state, order by vendor descending (to make null values appear last), and pick the first or default item matching the state from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = this.context.table.FirstOrDefault(a=>(a.vendor == "VendorA" || a.vendor == null) && a.state == "LA");
```

Comment: According to your answer 
var value = this.context.table.FirstOrDefault(a=>(a.vendor == "VendorA" || a.vendor == null) && a.state == "NY");
This will give me 1000, which is incorrect for me.

Comment: var value = this.context.table.FirstOrDefault(a=>(a.vendor == "VendorA" && a.state== "NY") || ( a.vendor == null && a.state == "LA");

Comment: I am asking about a generic method, not a static one. Please check the question, I had edited this for easiness.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Find` method:

```
var value = this.context.table.Find(a=>a.vendor == "VendorA" && a.state == "LA");
```

Please, see this performance considerations [Find() vs. Where().FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335015/find-vs-where-firstordefault)

UPDATE:

One call to database:

```
var values = this.context.table
    .Where(a=>a.vendor == Vendor && a.state == State || a.vendor == null 
        && a.state == State).ToList();
```

Comment: The performance question would be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032709/performance-of-find-vs-firstordefault

Comment: I am not worried about performance of find or where. 
Can I do this will one DB Call?

Comment: Yes with this I will get two rows, check my update in the question so that it will make more understandable.

Comment: @sagar43 I've just seen that you want to make just one call to DB. What another question do you have?