# "Find" method should be used instead of the "FirstOrDefault" extension

Tags: c#, linq, sonarqube, .net-6.0

I was happily using `FirstOrDefault()` method to get first element satisfying the condition. But from sometime, I am getting sonarqube warning **"Find" method should be used instead of the "FirstOrDefault" extension**.

Please let me know if `Find()` is better than `FirstOrDefault()` or it is just sonarqube's over optimization.

I am getting the above mentioned sonar warning in below given code:
[image]

Please refer the above code screen shot and also suggest how to re-write the same code with `Find()` method to remove the sonarqube warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find() vs. Where().FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335015/find-vs-where-firstordefault)

Comment: LINQ to what? Objects? EF Core? There's a huge difference. In EF Core, `Find` loads and *caches* an object by primary key, which means next time you request the same PK you get the original object

Comment: `Find` doesn't find the first element that satisfies a condition, it finds the only element with those specific primary key values. There can't be multiple rows with the same PK in a table

Comment: One distinction to be highlighted regardless of the source collection: In the case where the match is not found, .Find() will return *null* whereas .FirstOrDefault() will return the *default value for the type*, which will only be null for reference types. If you need an exception to be thrown, rather than null or default, you will use `.First()` instead. Essentially you have options and you should choose what you actually need/plan to check against

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold, I have added the screen shot of the code where I am getting the sonar warning.

Comment: `Find` vs `FirstOrdefault` two things in EF. Find give you data by Id but it first check the context to see the entity exist otherwise make a database query. Where as FirstOrDefault always make Database query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.find?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: While one should simply read the manual to answer this, there is enough information here to open this question, there is specific documentation and no room for opinions

Comment: What you posted returns an array. Arrays have no `Find` method, but there's a static `Array.Find<T> (T[] array, Predicate<T> match);`, completely different from what everyone assumed until now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos read the spec for the error message [RSPEC-6602](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-6602) Applies to [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find), [Array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find) and [ImmutableList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1.find) While you have misinterpreted the request, OP gave us all we need

Comment: @BrijeshKumarTripathi In this case, using Array.Find is a micro-optimization. Use whatever suits you best. The problem with these code quality tools is that they can't evaluate (yet?) what you're *actually* doing, and thus always issue their warnings.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller but not LINQ as the question said. As for the warning (not error message) there's no link to it in the question itself. You're making assumptions based on an answer. SonarQube is not as good as eg Resharper and often gets things wrong. `Because it's faster` isn't an answer either. Why is it faster compared to a `foreach` loop? The duplicate shows why.

Comment: Please help to reopen this question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thata a horrible dup, OP is specifically asking about the sonar error message, not the theory behind it. OP never mentioned LINQ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think it's fair to say these are assumptions. There's only one Sonar rule with that warning message, and the documentation explains that it *can* be faster and includes benchmarks and examples for when you might want to swap.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller the OP explicitly mentioned LINQ from the start. `I was happily using FirstOrDefault() LINQ method`

Comment: See the [sonarqube] tag and pretty much everything else OP mentions. If you don't understand the question, don't do any action on it, your input on this post has been the only real distraction from OP getting the answers that they need.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Sonar docs](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-6602/), it's for improved performance:

> Both the `List.Find` method and `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault` method can be used to find the first element that satisfies a given condition in a collection. However, `List.Find` can be faster than `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault` for List objects. For small collections, the performance difference may be minor, but for large collections, it can make a noticeable difference. The same applies for ImmutableList and arrays too.

Comment: This is a question about LINQ, not List. There's no `Find` in LINQ. EF Core has a Find that loads and caches objects by primary key

Comment: Not true @PanagiotisKanavos [List<T>.Find(Predicate<T>) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-7.0). Although the EF Find implementation is different to the List extension method.

Comment: The linked help here is pretty specific on "when" sonarcube detects it. So we have a close idea what the author has. Upvoted.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller that's not a LINQ method at all. It's a List-only method. It can't be used with any other IEnumerable- or IQueryable-derived container

Comment: That is specifically the `Find` implementation that sonarqube is referring to. Look at the documentation and navigate through to the references.

Comment: It is important to note that in EF, `Find` can be much faster than `First(OrDefault)` because it checks the cached records first, where as the latter method will execute a query against the underlying store. So in EF they are not directly interchangeable in all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You have not told us what type of object you are dealing with, but basically, if you are working with in-memory collections like `List<T>`, `Find()` can be more efficient, especially with large lists, because it can optimize the search using direct indexing. However, if you need to work with other data sources (such as databases) or prefer a more generalized approach, `FirstOrDefault()` is a suitable choice.

**

Now that you've edited your question, the answer is easier. The `GetMethods()` function returns an array (list of). So `Find()` will be the best approach given the above explanation.

Comment: Find() is not a method on an array.  So the question I have is, is there a performance increase if you have to convert an array to a List to be able to call Find?